# Understanding JSONDecodeError when using JsonOutputParser

Tags: python, langchain

I am just getting started with output-parsers and I'm impressed with their usefulness when they work properly. I have, however, run into a case where every now and then, a chain returns an error that seems to be related to the JsonOutputParser that I use, as indicated by the following (condensed) error message:

```
JSONDecodeError
JsonOutputParser.parse_result(self, result, partial)
156 # Parse the JSON string into a Python dictionary
--> 157 parsed = parser(json_str)
159 return parsed
122 # If we got here, we ran out of characters to remove
123 # and still couldn't parse the string as JSON, so return the parse error
124 # for the original string.
--> 125 return json.loads(s, strict=strict)
```

According to [this post here](https://www.reddit.com/r/LangChain/comments/17hep0o/comment/k6na6nd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web3x&utm_name=web3xcss&utm_term=1&utm_content=share_button) this could be related to there not being "enough tokens left to fully generate my output", which seems to be in line with the error message above:

```
122 # If we got here, we ran out of characters to remove
```

although I am not fully sure what that means or how it can be fixed.

Has anybody encountered this problem before and could offer some guidance? I must admit that I'm feeling kind of stumped, especially since the error can't be reproduced reliably and only occurs every other time I run my script.

Answer (score 1):

Examining the [unit tests](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.12/libs/core/tests/unit_tests/output_parsers/test_json.py#L238) for `JsonOutputParser.parse_partial_json()` will help you understand what's going on.

```py
TEST_CASES_PARTIAL = [
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}', '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo', '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo"}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo}', '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo}"}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo[', '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo["}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo\\"', '{"foo": "bar", "bar": "foo\\""}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar":', '{"foo": "bar"}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", "bar"', '{"foo": "bar"}'),
    ('{"foo": "bar", ', '{"foo": "bar"}'),
]


@pytest.mark.parametrize("json_strings", TEST_CASES_PARTIAL)
def test_parse_partial_json(json_strings: Tuple[str, str]) -> None:
    case, expected = json_strings
    parsed = parse_partial_json(case)
    assert parsed == json.loads(expected)
```

`parse_partial_json()` attempts to parse invalid JSON strings by truncating characters from the string until it's able to parse a valid JSON string.

```
{"foo": "bar", "bar"  # original LLM response

is truncated to...

{"foo": "bar"}        # valid JSON response
```

This is a best-effort approach to parsing invalid JSON responses from LLMs. As we know, LLMs are not guaranteed to return valid JSON. When the function is not able to parse the LLM response, the original parsing error is returned, which is the error you received.

#### Recommended Next Steps

1. Log the raw LLM response to see what string is actually being returned.
2. Most likely, the only thing that can be done at this point is to retry the LLM call or return an error to the end user.
3. It's possible that the LLM response is actually "partially JSON parseable" (i.e. a missed edge case). If so, you may want to consider adding a new test case to the unit test and updating the implementation of `parse_partial_json()`.

#### References:

1. [`JsonOutputParser.parse_partial_json()` (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.12/libs/core/langchain_core/output_parsers/json.py#L49)
2. [`JsonOutputParser.parse_partial_json()` unit test (GitHub)](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/blob/v0.1.12/libs/core/tests/unit_tests/output_parsers/test_json.py#L238)

Comment: awesome, thank you. I will give Output-fixing Parser and Retry Parser a try.